# MS Excel select rows based on font color

Tags: excel, vba, button, macros

I had a big amount of data about employees contract, a macro had created to auto change the font color to "RED" color for outdated employees rows and MsgBox pop-up to alert user amount of outdated data.

Below are the coding.

```
Sub Worksheet_Activate()

  Dim startCell As Integer, endCell As Integer
  Dim column As Integer
  Dim CountCells As Integer
  Dim x As Integer

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")

  lastrow = Range("L1048576").End(xlUp).Row

  CountCells = 0

  For i = 4 To lastrow

      If Range("L" & i).Value <> "" And Now <> "" Then

          If Range("L" & i).Value <= Now Then

              Range("L" & i).Font.ColorIndex = 3

                  If Range("L" & i).Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then

                     CountCells = CountCells + 1

                  End If
          End If
      End If
  Next i

     MsgBox CountCells & " expiring"

  End With
End Sub
```

Now i need the Excel to auto select each of them by a single click of button, problem facing was:

- which button should be use? Form Control button or ActiveX control button?
- 3 button are needed, (1) Auto select (2) copy and paste (3) delete each selected row.
- how to write code for each of the button?
- after user click the (1) button, it will auto select each RED data.
- then by pressing (2) button, it will copy them to new worksheet.
- lastly when user press the (3) button, each selected rows will be delete because only deleted each of them only the remain data will replacing the blank space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to loop through your cells. Set a Conditional Formatting rule to turn the font color red when the dates in column L is less than Now. With that in place, a [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) can filter on the red font cells.

```
Sub red_font_cells()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'turn off AutoFilter if it is on
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        'set a CF rule for <Now
        With .Range(.Cells(2, "L"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp))
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$L2<NOW()")
                .Font.Color = vbRed
            End With
        End With
        'add an AutoFilter for red font cells
        With .Range(.Cells(1, "L"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=vbRed, _
                        Operator:=xlFilterFontColor
        End With
        'deal with the red font cells
        With .Range(.Cells(2, "L"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp))
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    'select them (there are better ways to get things done)
                    '.Select
                    'copy them to sheet2 (do not need Select for this)
                    .Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A1")
                    'delete them
                    .EntireRow.Delete
                End With
            End If
        End With
        'turn off AutoFilter
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

I would use an ActiveX type button. You can right-click them to View Code.

Comment: yes bro, it's working, but not suitable for me, because once it run, the outdated employees direct copy pasted in sheet 2 and deleted. Is that possible for me to use back my code and create those 3 button?  (1) Auto select (2) copy and paste (3) delete each selected row. These let users have more control on the data.

Comment: Actually, I left the button coding for you. I would think that an **[enthusiastic programmer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)** like you would welcome the challenge. The purpose of my response here was to show you a better way of identifying and then isolating dates less than today.

Comment: Em...if i just copy your code start from the comment "deal with the red font cells" to the end paste on the ActiveX type button, it wont run. "Compile error: Invalid or Unqualified reference" highlighted on  ".Cells".

Comment: ok, I copy the whole code to the button, it run, but it only copy and pasted those data in column "L", others (from A to L) not included. is that possible to change?

Comment: Have a look two lines below that. If you want the entire row copied then use `.EntireRow.Copy`.

Comment: Alright, I done it, even though it is not like my expectation, but Thx any way~ By the way I'm new in vba, so a lot of coding in your parts i not understand, that's why i cant modify it by self :(

Comment: Hey bro, I noticed another problem. After the first time copy and pasted on Sheet 2, those data will be overwrite on second time i click the button due to it paste on the same place "A1". Is that any solutions???

Comment: Pasting to the next available row is a very basic concept. Please try to do a little research before chiming in with more questions. The answer to your last question was two lines down from the code you were trying to modify. A simple search through [excel-vba] should produce numerous examples of the solution to your new question.

Comment: sorry bro, i cant understand what you trying to tell me, 2 line down from the code that i going to modify...er....can make it more direct@@?what should I change?